# How to convert special symbols in filenames?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of genomic variants, and I have to export it in a `.tsv` file. I'm actually using this:

```
write.table(store, file=paste(variant, ".tsv", sep=""), sep="\t")
```

Problem is that "variant" is something like "G>G/A". How can I convert ">" and "/"?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you expect to convert to? Otherwise `gsub(pattern = ">|/", replacement = "", x = "G>G/A")` will remove those symbols from a strig

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! I needed a replacement of those symbols because they cannot be used as filenames.

Comment: Ok, good. Then I would advise you to use more general pattern`pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]"`, which will replace all non alphanumeric characters with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: `?gsub` or `?chartr`